# Embedded code app overrides the main code

Tags: html, css, embed, blackboard

I am trying to create code for a school website - it's basically an embedded code app on a pre-built site (Blackboard/Schoolwires site).

I'm VERY much an amateur and often pull from Codepen as my baseline, then edit and adapt to make it work for me. The problem I run into is that the embed code sometimes overrides the site code -- for example, the headline formatting in the embed spills onto the Blackboard header/footer.

I have tried to contain the embed code in a div class and a few other things, but I'm missing something. The page I am referring to in this instance is [HERE](https://www.wsfcs.k12.nc.us/Page/122658).

Any help would be appreciated! I am a teacher just trying to help update this site with my limited knowledge of code and I am definitely missing a lot.

Comment: The code is too long to post, but here is a link to a Codeine version: https://codepen.io/gbbartlett/pen/wvmbRyq?

Comment: Would an iframe help you? That would prevent interaction problems, but it would also prevent interaction between your code and the school's website, should you need that.

Answer (score 1):

You have to give the CSS that overrides the main code.

Also, you have to share the main code that's prewritten and the HTML code
where you want to apply your design. Otherwise, it will be tough
for others to identify the problem and make it for you.